# подключение к базе данных по выбору любого значения из combobox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

У меня есть код с подключением к базам данных к Postgre и SQL Server. Как мне с помощью combobox'а сделать, чтобы по выбору нужного элемента в нем, формировало и выводило нужную строку подключения в textbox'е.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас строка у меня формируется при загрузки формы путем выгрузки данных с XML-файла, а теперь не могу догнать как чтобы формировалась при выборе элемента в combobox'e

Comment: Есть такой паттерн `Abstract Factory`, вот его и нужно вам реализовать в данном случае.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте `класс` "подключения", в котором содержатся свойства самого подключения (сервер, логин, пароль, порт и т.д.). Вносите в комбо-бокс `объекты` класса "подключения". При переключении задайте событие, где из самого комбо-бокса будет тянуться выбранный `объект` и его свойства будут использоваться для создания нового подключения.
Сами свойства подключения храните в json (просто рекомендация).

Например:

```
public class StoredSqlConnection
{
    public string Name;
    public string DataSource;
    public string InitialCatalog;
    public string User;
    public string Password;
    public string overrid ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

Читайте из файла этот объект и добавляйте в комбо-бокс:

```
comboBox1.Iems.Add(new StoredSqlConnection {<присвойте параметры какие нужно>});
```

А далее при событии `SelectedIndexChanged` запускайте переподключение:

```
StoredSqlConnection conn = (StoredSqlConnection)(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
<ваша процедура подключения>(conn);
```

Comment: я так понимаю, должно быть в таком случае 2 класса, если 2 базы данных, каждый со своими данными?

Comment: @erleug Достаточно одного класса. Далее вы создаете сколько угодно экземпляров этого класса. Класс должен быть универсальным и заточенным одновременно под все возможные типы БД которые могут быть вами использованы. Я бы, для данного примера использовал список экземпляров класса. Т.е. List<StoredSqlConnection>. В не бы я напихал все варианты подключений что мне нужны. И потом бы их использовал.

Comment: и public string overrid ToString(), я так понимаю имелось ввиду public override string ToString()?

Comment: @erleug << так понимаю имелось ввиду public override string ToString()>> конечно

Comment: спасибо, буду пробывать, только если честно не совсем понятно,я создал экземпляры с данными, и теперь как использовать экземпляр, чтобы выводило в текстбокс нужные данные